# Use data from different tables in a view component

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have several tables in a database, and I want to use data from different tables in one view component. What can I write in return view command?

```cs
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    //return $"{db.}"
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you have a situation like:

```
var foos = await db.Foos.ToListAsync();
var bars = await db.Bars.ToListAsync();

return View(???);
```

Where you want to pass in both datasets, but of course, you only get one bite at that apple. If that is the case, then you simply need a view model - a class that can encompass both of these datasets, so you can return that.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var model = new MyViewModel
{
    Foos = await db.Foos.ToListAsync(),
    Bars = await db.Bars.ToListAsync()
};

return View(model);
```